# Conditional probability with multiple variables in evidence

Tags: probability

6.2% of population suffers from a specific disease $A$. 9% of population suffers from a specific condition $C$ and out of this group , 18.1% has the disease $A$. The disease can be tested with 99% sensitivity $P(T^+|A)$ and 98% specificity $P(T^-|A^c)$. Given a positive result and the fact that the patient suffers from the condition, what is the probability that he/she suffers the disease.

I tackled this problem with the bayes' rule. Lets denote the probabilities $P(A)=0.062$, $P(C) = 0.09$, $P(A|C) = 0.181$.

EDIT 2: The probability would be

\begin{align}
P(A | C \cap T^+) &= \frac{P(C \cap T^+ |A)P(A)}{P(C \cap T^+)}.
\end{align}
If we assuming conditional independence, we can transform the terms as such:
\begin{align}
P(C\cap T^+|A) &=P(C|A)P(T^+|A) \quad\text{per conditional independence,} \\
P(C\cap T^+|A) &= \frac{P(A|C)P(C)} {P(A)} P(T^+|A) = \frac{0.181\cdot 0.09} {0.062}0.99 =0.260 \\
1 &= P(A^c| C \cap T^+) + P(A | C \cap T^+) \\
1 &= \frac{P(C \cap T^+ | A^c)P(A^c)}{P(C \cap T^+)} +  \frac{P(C \cap T^+ | A)P(A)}{P(C \cap T^+)}  \quad |\cdot P(C \cap T^+) \\
P(C \cap T^+) &= P(C|A^c)P(T^+|A^c)P(A^c)+P(C|A)P(T^+|A)P(A) \\
P(C \cap T^+) &= \frac{P(A^c|C)P(C)P(A^c)}{P(A^c)}(1-P(T^-|A^c))+\frac{P(A|C)P(C)P(A)} {P(A)}P(T^+|A) \\
P(C \cap T^+) &= (1-P(A|C))P(C)(1-P(T^-|A^c))+P(A|C)P(C)P(T^+|A) \\
P(C \cap T^+) &= (1-0.181)\cdot0.09\cdot(1-0.98)+0.181\cdot0.09\cdot0.99 \\
P(C \cap T^+) &= 0.0176013
\end{align}
Then the probability should be:
\begin{align}
P(A | C \cap T^+) &= \frac{0.260 \cdot 0.062}{0.0176}=0.916.
\end{align}
But that value is definitely too small, so I got it wrong somewhere.

Comment: I have doubts that $P((C\cap T+)\cap A)=P(A\cap C)\cdot P(T+)$ is true. This is only true, if $A\cap C$ and $T+$ are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is with this step:

$$P(C \cap T^+) = P(C|A^c)P(T^+|A^c)+P(C|A)P(T^+|A) $$

should be:

$$P(C \cap T^+) = P(C|A^c)P(T^+|A^c)P(A^c)+P(C|A)P(T^+|A)P(A) $$

This makes $P(C \cap T^+ ) \approx 0.0176 $

Thus $P(A|C \cap T^+) \approx 0.916$

Comment: Good catch! I calculated the result with taking that into account, but out results still differs. Maybe you or I made a mistake.

Comment: Thanks!  So, we agree on P(ACT), your second term, at 0.016127.  The difference is in the first P(A'CT); I have 0.003294 and you have 0.001474.  Let me double-check my work on that one, since I used a slightly different method.

Comment: I think your calculations are correct!  I'll edit my answer.